# Which is better: class with single rule or inline style?

Tags: html, css

Is it better to create a class for a single rule (e.g. float:left;) or apply it using inline style?

Comment: If you have a lot of these, then you'll save some space by having class="fleft" or whatever, instead of style='float:left'. Also if you decide to change your style, you can just change it in the sheet to float right, or remove it all together - rather than requiring you to update all your files. I think the better way to go really is to define your elements like class="navigation", then define that as float left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never better to use inline styles no matter what for both readability and maintainability.

Same would go for inline JavaScript.

It makes it a lot easier for yourself if you seperate the logic and the view stuff.

Comment: I agree, but you should better to give some reference.

Answer (score 3):

The layout should be separated from the content, so you should have the style in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

Better to create a class.

1. You never know when you will want to use that style again.  Having it in a class can make it easier to reuse.  For instance, an `img.right` class can be used to `float` all your images to the right (with the class right).
2. Inline styles are difficult to override should you want to do so in the future.
3. Classes on elements make those elements easier to manipulate with javascript and other programming languages.
4. It keeps you code clean and easy to read, for you and for others.